# How to validate session in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 5.2,
I added a verification code input in register form,
verification code was saved in session when making it,
the question is:
How to write the validation rule of verification code in function `validator`,

**AuthController.php**

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    $verification_code_session = $request->session()->get('verification_code', '');
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
        'verification_code' => '',// How to write the validation rule? 
    ]);
}
```

**Add:**

add an argument:`Request $request` like this:

```
protected function validator(array $data,Request $request)
{
    $verification_code_session = $request->session()->get('verification_code', '');

    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
        'verification_code' => 'required|in:' . $verification_code_session
    ]);
```

error:

```
FatalThrowableError in AuthController.php line 56:
Type error: Argument 2 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController::validator() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, none given, called in D:\wnmp\www\laravel-entrust\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers.php on line 69
```

Where do I ought to use `$this`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you could do that using the `in` pattern :

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    $verification_code_session = \Request::session()->get('verification_code', '');

    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
        'verification_code' => 'required|in:' . $verification_code_session
    ]);
}
```

Comment: There is an error: `ErrorException in AuthController.php line 58:
Undefined variable: request` .How to add argument/s?

Comment: It depends on the context. If you are in a FormRequest use $this else add the Request $request in the arguments of validator function

Comment: I have imported Illuminate\Http\Request

Comment: It should work with the Request facade. I update my answer and let me know